# Generating static pages for React

Tags: html, reactjs, babeljs, static-files

The goal is to have my React app running client-side on Amazon S3 (CDN), and have the news files generated so that I can have meta tags for social sharing (mostly because of Facebook).

So for example if someone shares http://website.com/news/343434 then I would have the file /news/343434/index.html on Amazon S3, which would only have the head section filled for the meta tags, and one div in the body with the id root for the React app to attach.

The problem with this method is that the generated files don't know the reference to the main.js file because of the hash that is added to the file name for cache busting. And even if I did, that would mean I would need to re-generate all the news files whenever the React app is deployed, since the hash would change.

I had another idea of having a lambda function on AWS that would basically return the template file filled with the correct meta tags and the reference to the main-{hash}.js file, etc. It seems to be the best solution that I can think of.

Are there any other solutions that might work well?

Answer (score 1):

There are frameworks that address server-side rendering for React Apps. Check https://github.com/zeit/next.js/ for example.